# Rank specific columns of 2D arrays inside a 3D Array

Tags: python, numpy, ranking

I have many 2D arrays inside of a 3D array.

Let’s assume that shape of the 3D array is (3, 5, 5).  Therefore, I have 3 2D Arrays of shape (5, 5).

Column #4 (idx of 3) in each 2D array has a certain value as per below. I want to replace those values with corresponding ranks in descending order. The highest value will correspond to the maximum number of records (I.e. shape[1]) in 2D array, and the lowest value will have a rank of 1 (not 0).

I know that this could be achieved using NumPy’s argsort() function. But what I want to avoid is looping through the 3D array.
Could you please suggest the most efficient, native NumPy and loop-free alternatives?

Thank you!

```
[[[1. 0. 0.10. 0.]
  [2. 0. 0. 9. 0.]
  [3. 0. 0. 8. 0.]
  [4. 0. 0. 7. 0.]
  [5. 0. 0. 6. 0.]]
 [[1. 0. 0. 199. 0.]
  [2. 0. 0. 198. 0.]
  [3. 0. 0. 196. 0.]
  [4. 0. 0. 190. 0.]
  [5. 0. 0. 160. 0.]]
 [[1. 0. 0. 999. 0.]
  [2. 0. 0. 870. 0.]
  [3. 0. 0. 270. 0.]
  [4. 0. 0. 100. 0.]
  [5. 0. 0. 80. 0.]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
arr[:, :, 3] = arr[:, :, 3].argsort(axis=1).argsort(axis=1) + 1
```

Note that using `argsort` twice is necessary to obtain "ranks".

Comment: Thank you @Chrysophylaxs! This worked like a charm. I've accepted this as an answer. The only question I have, if you don't mind, is - how can modify above to rank multiple columns (not one) at the same time? Say columns 3, 5, 6, and 9 all at once. Would that even be possible?

Comment: Hi @Taz, I'm glad it worked! I am a bit unsure about your followup question, but one thing you can do is: `arr[:, :, [3, 5, 6, 9]] = arr[:, :, [3, 5, 6, 9]].argsort(axis=1).argsort(axis=1) + 1`. This would apply the same trick to each 3rd, 5th, 6th and 9th column. In your example however, 5, 6, and 9 wouldn't work since the number of columns in each matrix is only 5.

Comment: Hi @Chrysophylaxs, that is exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much, again! You are right - the matrix from above is just a sample.

Comment: Very last question @Chrysophylaxs if you don't mind :). How can I rank column values in the ascending order? i.e.: the smallest column values will get assigned the highest rank. I tried    .argsort(axis=1).argsort(axis=1)[::-1] + 1 but it does not produce correct results. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Taz: I would recommend: `arr[:, :, 3] = arr[:, :, 3].argsort(axis=1)[:, ::-1].argsort(axis=1) + 1`. Alternatively, you could use the negative of the array before you sort to sort in descending order, or simply take `6 -` the current result.

Comment: Thank you @Chrysophylaxs, just realized that nan values are being ranked too by argsort and that is causing some issues, but your answer was 100% correct. Thanks again.